# How to use multiple development languages

Tags: c, delphi, dll, wolfram-mathematica, multilingual

I program in Delphi (D7 and D2006) on Windows XP (migrating in the near future to Windows 7). I need to use a mathematical library for some of the work I am doing and most of the math libraries (I am inclining towards Mathematica at present) I have looked at will produce compiled C code. Such code will provide specific functionality to my main programs.

I have a very basic question - given this development setup - how do I start utilising the compiled c code from Delphi? I really need baby steps to get me started on the process.

Comment: Are you planning to use  **Mathematica** for producing C code?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your answer. Could you please post a pointer to the conversion software/feature for going from Mathematica to C?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you would use Mathematica for code generation either. There are perfectly good maths libraries out there, highly optimized, proven and stable. Maybe you want to describe your problem in more detail so someone can give you a hint at what to use.

Comment: @belisarius http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.htmlit is not strictly conversion at all, a link up.

Comment: @Orbling That is what I suspected ... thanks!

Comment: belisarius: Mathematica 8 has some tools to produce C-code http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/symbolicc/

Comment: @Belisarius I obtained the reference to code production from the description of features on the Wolfram site. This describes (at least) two approaches to obtaining c code to perform mathematical calculations: one that relies on the Mathematica library being present (especially higher level functions); the other describes the production of compiled C code.

Comment: @belisarius Having said that, it can generate full C code that can be statically compiled, but only for a subset of operations.  As it provides compiled libraries to link against.  For full use, there are shared libraries to link against, but that requires Mathematica to be installed obviously. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCodeGenerator/guide/CCodeGenerator.html

Comment: @Jim Brissom I am not fixated on Mathematica, a good math library would do the trick too. This still leaves the problem of linking the library or the generated code or the compiled code into my primary programs.

Comment: @Yaro That will be indeed a nice feature ... when I get the funding :)

Comment: @Orbling _equires Mathematica to be installed obviously_ :D

Comment: @belisarius The "minimal" static libraries are probably fairly comprehensive, though I can't find a list of what they include.

Comment: If this feature had been available 10 years ago next month when I had to convert an entire post-doctoral research application (not mine I might add) from Mathematica to C++, I would have been quite pleased!!

Comment: @Orbling You are not alone :D

Comment: @belisarius It was in waveform analysis for music too (background paper: http://ismir2000.ismir.net/posters/shroeter_ruger.pdf)!  Converting the code by hand was a lot better however as my version was many thousands of times faster, literally.

Comment: @Orbling Very interesting! Thanks for the pointer. A friend of mine is developing a commercial app for _comparing_ musical records ... I'll suggest him to contact you someway

Comment: @belisarius Well it was a long time ago and that is not my research, though I did a lot on the subject during the process, very interesting field, but with limited success, the timbre of certain instruments is a nightmare. [Apologies for hijacking this thread to other readers.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done quite a bit of this with my FE product [OrcaFlex](http://www.orcina.com/SoftwareProducts/OrcaFlex).  You have two options to link to your C code from Delphi: static or dynamic.  I link statically because it makes distribution and versioning much easier.  But it's really quite a trick to get it to work statically and you have to rely on a number of undocumented aspects of Delphi.

I suspect that for your needs dynamic linking is best.  Basically you need to compile and link your C code into a DLL.  I recommend using the Borland C compiler to do this.  You can use the free command line version BCC55 to do this.  The advantage of using Borland C is that it makes the same assumptions about the 8087 floating point unit as Delphi does.  If you build with MSVC then you will find that MS have elected not to raise floating point exceptions.  Borland C does raise floating point exceptions.  This is a bit of a corner case but it becomes relevant if you are trying to ship a product that you need to be robust.

You should know that the C code will, by default, use the C calling convention and I'd just stick with that.  You bring it into Delphi by declaring the external routine as cdecl calling convention.

The other thing you need to take care on is defining a clear interface between the two modules.  You need to make sure that exceptions don't cross the module boundary and that you don't pass any special types (e.g. Delphi strings) across the boundary.  So for a string use a PChar (or even better PAnsiChar or PWideChar to be sure that it won't change meaning when you upgrade to Delphi 2009 and later).

Answer (score 3):

I have been very happy with the SDL Library from Lohninger (http://www.lohninger.com/mathpack.html). It is written in Delphi and compiles right into your application, so there are no bundling or  calling convention problems or floating point usage differences, as discussed by other responses in this thread.

Take a look at what he includes. If you're lucky, your needs will be met by his library and you'll be able to use it!

Comment: I did look at the SDL library which does appear to be very useful. However, it did not support the functions I specifically wanted. I have now gone with TPMath. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you currently have Mathematica installed, go to the documentation centre and lookup `guide/CLanguageInterface` otherwise that guide is [available on the web](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CLanguageInterface.html) and have a good read there.

My understanding is that Mathematica can generate C-programs that link up with the Mathematica engine via MathLink if you need full function, or if you only need lower-level features then it is capable of generating code that can be statically linked with compiled Mathematica libraries.  So that standalone code is possible.

See the [Code Generator documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/CodeGeneration.html).

If you can convert the C programs in to [DLLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library), then accessing such external functions from Delphi is relatively simple with *external* declarations.

```
function MathematicaRoutine(const x : double) : double; external 'MyInterface.dll';
```

There are bound to be a great number of complexities in getting this to work if you need to achieve a static bind, for use where Mathematica is not installed, if indeed it is possible.  I have never attempted it.

Answer (score 2):

You can mix your project with Delphi and C++ (Builder) code using RAD Studio. Put the automatically created C code into a C++ Builder file (.cpp) and for the rest add Delphi files.